# Inner joins returning duplicate records

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, distinct, distinct-on

I write this query to retrieve data from 3 different tables.

Here [all columns i selected are from the first and the second table], data is retrieved as i actually need :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD.salary_component,SS.posting_date,SS.payroll_entry,
                        SD.parentfield,SD.amount,SS.employee,SS.name
FROM`tabSalary Detail` SD
INNER JOIN  `tabSalary Slip` SS 
    ON SS.name=SD.parent
INNER JOIN `tabGL Entry` GL
    ON GL.against_voucher=SS.payroll_entry
WHERE SS.employee='EMP0110' AND 
                     SS.posting_date='2020-03-11' AND 
                     SD.parentfield != 'indebtedness' AND
                     SS.payroll_entry='HR-PRUN-2019-01027';
```

the desired and the query result is

```
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000 EMP0110  Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000 EMP0110  Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04
```

=======

But , when i selected two column in the third table something goes wrong and data is duplicated :

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD.salary_component,SS.posting_date,SS.payroll_entry,
                        SD.parentfield,SD.amount,SS.employee,SS.name
                        GL.credit,GL.debit
FROM`tabSalary Detail` SD
INNER JOIN  `tabSalary Slip` SS 
    ON SS.name=SD.parent
INNER JOIN `tabGL Entry` GL
    ON GL.against_voucher=SS.payroll_entry
WHERE SS.employee='EMP0110' AND 
                     SS.posting_date='2020-03-11' AND 
                     SD.parentfield != 'indebtedness' AND
                     SS.payroll_entry='HR-PRUN-2019-01027';
```

the second query result is 54 duplicated rows

```
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    300.000000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    300.000000  0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    500.000000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    500.000000  0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    3600.000000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    3600.000000 0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    445.890000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    445.890000  0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    336.990000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    336.990000  0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    95.000000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    95.000000   0.000000

AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    1150.000000
AAAA    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    1150.000000 0.000000
===================================================================================================================================
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    300.000000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    300.000000  0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    500.000000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    500.000000  0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    3600.000000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    3600.000000 0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    445.890000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    445.890000  0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    336.990000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    336.990000  0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    95.000000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    95.000000   0.000000

BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    1150.000000
BBBB    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    300.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    1150.000000 0.000000
===================================================================================================================================
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    300.000000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    300.000000  0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    500.000000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    500.000000  0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    3600.000000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    3600.000000 0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    445.890000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    445.890000  0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    336.990000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    336.990000  0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    95.000000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    95.000000   0.000000

CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    1150.000000
CCCC    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    500.000000  EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    1150.000000 0.000000
===================================================================================================================================
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    300.000000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    300.000000  0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    500.000000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    500.000000  0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    3600.000000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    3600.000000 0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    445.890000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    445.890000  0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    336.990000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    336.990000  0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    95.000000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    95.000000   0.000000

DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    0.000000    1150.000000
DDDD    2020-03-11  HR-PRUN-2019-01027  earnings    3600.000000 EMP0110 Sal Slip-EMP0110-1911-04    1150.000000 0.000000
```

what is the wrong and what topics should i search to get the idea ?
finally , what is the best solution ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Use the First query as one table and join with `tabGL Entry` GL to resolve the issue

Comment: I don't understand your tables. Why are the salary_detail and salary_slip tables joined via name and a column called parent? Why not via some salary ID? Please give us detailed information on your tables. What do they represent? What are their unique keys? How are they related via foreign keys.

Comment: As to your first query: `DISTINCT` is very often a sign for a badly written query. How come you get duplicate rows in the first place? Can't you avoid them right away? Are your joins incomplete, thus producing them? In your second query you might want some aggregation. Don't know. Please show us sample data that demonstrates a case where you get duplicate result rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have edited the post

Comment: @ThorstenKettner name is like ID in my tables

Comment: You are showing now the expected result. Thank you for this. Now please edit your request again to also show the related entries in the three tables, so we see where the results come from.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner
Done . it seems that the [condition SD.parent field != 'indebtedness'] did not applied

Comment: Now you are showing two results, one for each query. Okay. But what do the tables contain? Please show the sample data for table `tabSalary Detail`, table `tabSalary Slip`, and table `tabGL Entry`.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that you want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT SD.salary_component, SS.posting_date, SS.payroll_entry,                       
       SD.parentfield, SD.amount, SS.employee, SS.name,
       SUM(GL.credit), SUM(GL.debit)
FROM `tabSalary Detail` SD INNER JOIN
     `tabSalary Slip` SS 
      ON SS.name = SD.parent INNER JOIN
      `tabGL Entry` GL
      ON GL.against_voucher=SS.payroll_entry
WHERE SS.employee = 'EMP0110' AND 
      SS.posting_date = '2020-03-11' AND 
      SD.parentfield <> 'indebtedness' AND
      SS.payroll_entry = 'HR-PRUN-2019-01027'
GROUP BY SD.salary_component, SS.posting_date, SS.payroll_entry,                       
         SD.parentfield, SD.amount, SS.employee, SS.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SD.salary_component,SS.posting_date,SS.payroll_entry,
                    SD.parentfield,SD.amount,SS.employee,SS.name
                    SUM(GL.credit) AS credit,SUM(GL.debit) AS debit
   FROM`tabSalary Detail` SD
INNER JOIN  `tabSalary Slip` SS 
   ON SS.name=SD.parent
INNER JOIN `tabGL Entry` GL
   ON GL.against_voucher=SS.payroll_entry
WHERE SS.employee='EMP0110' AND 
                 SS.posting_date='2020-03-11' AND 
                 SD.parentfield != 'indebtedness' AND
                 SS.payroll_entry='HR-PRUN-2019-01027'
GROUP BY SD.salary_component, SS.posting_date, SS.payroll_entry,                       
     SD.parentfield, SD.amount, SS.employee, SS.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that even a couple of rows of sample data showing the duplicates would be very helpful.

Typically what is happening is that the JOIN to the third table
 (ON GL.against_voucher=SS.payroll_entry)
combined with the lack of having any "GL." criteria in the WHERE clause is not specific enough to eliminate the creation of duplicates.

Thus having DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY will still produce duplicates in some fields even though the row is distinct.

If you provide a GOOD example of some duplicates then the syntax that will work will be easier to answer.

Comment: i have added it